# FileUploadField not working in wicket 1.4.17 with ie edge

Tags: java, internet-explorer, wicket, multipart, wicket-1.4

I am using wicket 1.4.17 and the browser IE edge

when I try to use `FileUploadField`  I get Exception:

ervletRequest does not contain multipart content. One possible solution is to explicitly call `Form.setMultipart(true)`, Wicket tries its best to auto-detect multipart forms

- I get in the `contentType = application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- In IE9 its work.

I expect to see after I added  Form.setMultipart(true) then `contentType=multipart`.

Comment: You might want to upgrade to a Wicket version that's actually supported, say version 6 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form is submitted with POST:

http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Error-with-FileUpload-quot-ServletRequest-does-not-contain-multipart-content-quot-td3512653.html

Comment: its submitted with post